# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception:app:multiDexListDebug

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm struggling to fix the problem that `Android Studio
Unable to create debug or signed apk`.

```
Task :app:multiDexListDebug FAILED
Task :app:multiDexListDebug in app Finished
:app:multiDexListDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 2.62 secs.
AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-linux Daemon #0: shutdown
```

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

**What went wrong:**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
    Error while merging dex archives: 
     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
     Program type already present: kotlin.StandardKt__SynchronizedKt
```

**Scenario tried:**

- enabled `multidex` true
- added dependency `Multidex 2.0.1`(android x)
- cleaning and rebuild project
- excluding `org.jetbrains.kotlin` from the major projects.
- tried using `api` & `runtimeOnly`

Comment: **Program type already present:** These errors mostly appear when there are two instances of libraries on a single project that conflicts with each other. Run `gradlew app:dependencies` (on Linux: `./gradlew app:dependencies`) to see your dependency tree and search for **kotlin.StandardKt__SynchronizedKt** and see how many times and where it appears. Removing one instance should solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063596/unable-to-create-debug-or-signed-apk

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul
I tried using the cmd `./gradlew app: dependencies` and searched for **kotlin.StandardKt__SynchronizedKt**  I didn't find it

Comment: @Muhammed Yalcin Kuru
Yes, the issue is similar as you posted. Not getting any leads at my end

Answer (score 0):

Once include the below code in your app level build.gradle and check

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```