# Unable to create debug or signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Can anyone guide me through this issue as I am unable to create `apk` through `Android Studio`? Please....

> **ERROR:** Program type already present: `kotlin.StandardKt__SynchronizedKt`

```
> Task :app:multiDexListDebug FAILED
Task :app:multiDexListDebug in app Finished
:app:multiDexListDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 2.62 secs.
AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-linux Daemon #0: shutdown
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Error while merging dex archives: 
     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
     Program type already present: kotlin.StandardKt__SynchronizedKt

**STACK TRACE**

 * Exception is:


org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
```

**Scenario tried:**

- Enabled `multidex true`
- Added dependency `Multidex 2.0.1(android x)`
- tried `cleaning` and `rebuild` project
- tried excluding `org.jetbrains.kotlin` from the major projects.

  `implementation (project(':ProjectName')){
    exclude group:'org.jetbrains.kotlin' ,module:'kotlin-stdlib'
  }`
- tried using `api` , `runtimeOnly`

Comment: Developer guide says it happens due to modules or libraries in your project using different sdk version. Check this for a solution : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#configure-project-wide-properties

Comment: have you mentioned android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" in your manifest file too?

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman Yes

Comment: make sure that you  aren't using two versions of google service.

Comment: @Bunny Checked both are same

Answer (score 0):

in the app level build.gradle mention:

```
defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
It is already added in the app gradle.I have also used the Multi dex dependency but still failing to create any of the build debug or signed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are conflict dependencies(causing duplication). That is usually occurs inner used dependencies. Mostly, gradle handles this error by selecting newer version of dependency. Possible solutions;

1- Follow [the steps and determine duplicated class location](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolution_errors) and [then exclude duplicated dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle)

2- Manually remove recently added dependencies and determine which causes error then try newer or older version of it.

Comment: Yalcin Kuru

Thanks it seems to work.But got a new 
**Error:** 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics

Comment: @Gulshan be sure that you only excluded  duplicated class. If that part is okey then you need to be sure you have excluded older version. This class might not be available in old version

Comment: Yalcin Kuru
Below is the amendment I made

**Added:**

 configurations.all {
        exclude group:"org.jetbrains.kotlin" ,module:"kotlin-stdlib"
    } 

Using this excludes the order version of group "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"and now I included the new version i.e

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"


Error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics

Comment: @Gulshan i think configurations.all excluding all the module but anyway you need it right ? so try implementation('com.example.m:m:1.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'x 
    }

Comment: Yalcin Kuru
Yes, I think I don't need `configuration.all`
And I tried `implementation('com.example.m:m:1.0') { exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'x }` 
**More detail**
`Error: kotlin.StandardKt__SynchronizedKt`
This file is present within this `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin`.I tried excuding this from all the implementation having it. But still unable to create the build.